Does $\int_1^\infty \frac{f_ng_n}{f_n^2+g_n} \, dx \to 0$ for $g_n < \frac{1}{x^3}$ and $f_n \to 0$?
Let $f_n, g_n : [1, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ be sequences of measurable functions such that
$$|g_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{x^3} \hspace{0.5cm} \forall \, x \in [1, \infty) \hspace{0.5cm} \mathrm{and} \hspace{0.5cm} f_n \to 0 \hspace{0.5cm} a.e. \,\, x \in [1, \infty)$$
Is it always true that $$\int_1^\infty \frac{f_ng_n}{f_n^2+g_n} \, dx \to 0 \, \, ?$$
First, I'd like to relax the condition $|g_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{x^3}$ to just $g_n(x) < \frac{1}{x^3}$ since $g_n$ is positive. Now, $g_n(x) \leq \frac{1}{x^3} \leq 1$, so all $g_n$'s are bounded by $1$ for every choice of $x$. Playing with the above integral, I get
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{f_ng_n}{f_n^2+g_n} \, dx \leq \int_1^\infty \frac{f_n \cdot \frac{1}{x^3}}{f_n^2+\frac{1}{x^3}} \, dx=\int_1^\infty \frac{f_n}{f_n^2x^3+1} \, dx$$
Now, $x^3 \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ but $f_n^2 \to 0$. If $f_n$ decreases more quickly than $x^3$ increases, then the denominator approaches $1$, giving us a decreasing integrand function $-$ but even then, a decreasing integrand function doesn't imply convergence to $0$ (e.g. take $\int \frac{1}{x}$). The way I see it, two things must be done here:

determine how $f_n^2 x^3$ behaves as $n \to \infty$ and $x \to \infty$
if $f_n^2$ dominates $x^3$, then if a convergence theorem can show that $\int f_n \to \int f = \int 0 = 0$, then the above integral converges to $0$

But it's not clear to me how to show either of these (assuming that the integral converges to $0$, which it may not)

The answer is NO. Try to find an exmaple with $g_n(x)=\frac 1 {x^{3}}$ for all $n,x$.

It should be $$\int_1^\infty \frac{f_ng_n}{f_n^2+g_n} , \mathrm{d}x \leq \int_1^\infty \frac{f_n \cdot \frac{1}{x^3}}{f_n^2+0} , \mathrm{d}x.$$ since you need to use a lower bound for $g_n$ in denominator.
